# Adding file path to each line of line of text

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying to find a way to add the file path to each line of printed text from a file.  So, for example if I have an mail log file (lets call it /var/log/mail.log) when I display the file I get lines in stdout such as:

```
    Jun 27 03:28:39 host courier-pop3d: LOGIN, user=bob@domain.net, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1], port=[2796]
    Jun 27 03:28:46 host courier-imaps: Connection, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1]
    Jun 27 03:28:46 host courier-imaps: LOGIN FAILED, method=CRAM-MD5, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1]
    Jun 27 03:28:52 host courier-imaps: LOGIN FAILED, user=alice@domain.com, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1]
    Jun 27 03:28:52 host courier-imaps: authentication error: Input/output error
    Jun 27 03:28:55 host courier-pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1]
    Jun 27 03:28:55 host courier-pop3d: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1]
```

Now what I need is for it to do is print the file into stdout and display:

```
    Jun 27 03:28:39 host courier-pop3d: LOGIN, user=bob@domain.net, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1], port=[2796] /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:46 host courier-imaps: Connection, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1] /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:46 host courier-imaps: LOGIN FAILED, method=CRAM-MD5, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1] /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:52 host courier-imaps: LOGIN FAILED, user=alice@domain.com, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1] /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:52 host courier-imaps: authentication error: Input/output error /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:55 host courier-pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1] /var/log/mail.log
    Jun 27 03:28:55 host courier-pop3d: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:1.1.1.1] /var/log/mail.log
```

I'm looking for a standard BASH command(s) for doing this since this needs to run on hundreds of different servers without installing addition programs.

Comment: If you don't care about the exact format, this simple command will work:  `grep -H "" mail.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not mind adding this information at the beginning instead of the end: `grep`'s `-H` switch enables prepending each matched line with the respective filename as given on the commmand line as well as a colon. In this case we ask `grep` to match any line:

```
grep -H "" /var/log/mail.log
```

Performance in my test was about 100 ms for 15.000 log lines.

Comment: That puts the filename at the **beginning** of each line instead of the **end** and then attempts to `grep ... /var/log/mail.log` (not an answer, you may need to amend)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, that is exactly what I wrote. The OP did not specify whether he or she cares about the position of the information inside the line. The advantage of this solution is its simplicity. It will not have the best performance however. But why do you think this is not an answer?

Comment: Actually after testing all the above answers this worked the best even though it put the file path at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to append any string to the end of every line, you can use `sed`.

```
sed 's/$/ INSERT_STRING_HERE/' InputFileName
```

For your specific problem, if you are trying to loop through a bunch of files, that file name should be available as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The following awk script will add the file name to each line:

```
awk '{ print $0, ARGV[1] }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one:

```
awk '{print $0" "FILENAME;}' /path/to/some/file
```